# how make a selection glow and then off in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone

hi i have a problem with the selection when I select a row in uitableviewcell it selects and turns to blue with out making any animation i mean normally when a row in table is selected it turns into blue and go off immediately like an animation. How to achieve that? Not deslecting a row....it is like highlight the cell and go off when cell is selected by user...Can any one help please....

Comment: If the answer below fixed your problem, be sure to "check" it as the accepted answer to give Ben S credit for helping you out.

Answer (score 10):

From the [Table View Programming Guide, Responding to Selections](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9-SW7):

In your [`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) method add the following:

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];`

"Selecting" does the blue-highlight animation, "deselecting" flashes it back to normal color. By adding a deselection as soon as it's selected you get the effect of flashing it with color.

If you want to avoid the whole coloring thing, you can use [`UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) as your cell style.

Comment: One more thing I need to make a check mark next to the cell row selected . I mean when I click on a row of particular table it navigates to next page where he can select his own row and it displays his selection as check mark at the end of cell . How to achieve this ...Please help me I am trying this from long time I cannot figure it out...Thank you inadvance...

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9-SW7 If your selection can only be one cell, look at Listing 6-3. If your selection can be more than one list, look at Listing 6-4.